# Adding a detail text labels to an existing array of strings, UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have this array in my UITableViewController.m

```
    self.movies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               @"Zardoz",
               @"Dark City",
               @"Inland Empire",
               @"Gangs of New York",
               @"Enemy",
               @"They Live",
               @"Lost Highway",
               nil];
```

I would like to initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2. I am trying to add a detailTextLabel to each corresponding to each movies IDBM rating(double). 
Do I create another array for the values? Thanks.

Comment: An array of dictionary of strings works. Don't keep two separate arrays. What happens when you need a third property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is to create a new class, literally something like:

```
@interface MovieObject

@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (copy) NSString *movieDescription;

@end
```

and then you can add objects of those type to your ***mutable*** array of movies:

```
newMovie = [[MovieObject alloc] init];
newMovie.title = @"Zardoz"
newMovie.movieDescription = @"Oscar Winner"
[self.movies addObject: newMovie];
```

and when you fetch those objects, you'll have both the title and the detail text to go with that movie title.

Comment: Do not name a property `description`. It will conflict with the standard `NSObject` method `description`. And the string properties should be `copy`, not `strong`.

Comment: $#$@#$ it all... I was only answering with about 1/4 of my brain (during a boring business meeting) while typing my answer.  Thanks for reminding me.